# Google Maps Marker double click zooming map

Tags: javascript, listener, google-maps-markers

I have placed several makers on a Google map, as follows -

```
var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: somePosition,
               map: map,
               title: 'My Marker',
               draggable: true
           });
```

and set up a number of listeners on the markers; click, dblclick, dragend & rightclick -

```
google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, 'dblclick', function (evt) {
               doStuffWith(newMarker);
           });
```

This all works, my problem is that when I double click my markers, the map also zooms in. I'd like the map to zoom in when you double click the map only, if I double click a marker I'd like my listener event to fire & the map NOT to zoom.

Is this possible ? Thank you.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186635/disable-double-left-click-on-google-map

Answer (score 2):

You can add

```
disableDoubleClickZoom: true
```

to the map options.

Comment: But what about if this is already done, and there is also a `dblclick` listener on the map itself? In a Browser it works, but in an Android Webview both `dblclick` events are triggered.